# Talking about general truths but within a context that uses past tense

Tags: tenses, past-tense

> Pikachu strolled along the street blissfully unaware that the Earth **is**
>   round.

or

> Pikachu strolled along the street blissfully unaware that the Earth **was**
>   round.

What is the rule/preference for such cases when we talk about general truths but within a context that uses the past tense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"unaware" has no tense.  It adopts the past tense of "strolled." See what happens in the present continuous tense:

> Pikachu is strolling along the street blissfully unaware that the
>   Earth is round.

When the verbal phrase is in the past tense, the reported thought becomes past.

> Pikachu strolled along the street blissfully unaware that the Earth
>   was round.

Tenses in indirect speech are explained here  [[BBC]](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv309.shtml)

Comment: Thank you. A very useful link. If this is the first time I mention *street*, should I use the indefinite article instead of definite one with it: "along a street"?

Comment: OK. Is it a mistake to use the indefinite article with the word *context* like I did in the title of this question? What is preferable here? *A*, *the* or no article at all?

Comment: The title is good.

Comment: @SiegfriedZaytsev - It is natural to say "strolling along the street" -- similar to "passing the time."

Comment: 'Pikachu strolled along the street blissfully unaware that the Earth was round."  There is a very basic error here. The Earth was round then and IS round even now. So we may say 'Pikachu strolled along the street blissfully unaware that the Earth IS round."

Comment: @Abhilaaj, You are trying to correct a *logical* error (which is not there anyway) by making a *grammatical* error  "Was" is the correct tense after "strolled"; and it implies the earth always was and is round even though P. was unaware of it..

Comment: May be Sir, you are right here. I just relied on what my English teachers told us in class at school level : Never change the tense of a fact or a truth, unless it was discovered later.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer "was round".

**Reasoning**

Pikachu was under a misapprehension. He thought the Earth was flat.

We can't say, "Pikachu thought the Earth is flat" because it isn't. Therefore we aren't describing a general truth. We have to say, "Pikachu thought the Earth was flat."

In order to match tenses we say, "Pikachu  was unaware that the Earth was round."

Comment: Saying "Pikachu was unaware that the Earth was round", you don't exclude changes on the shape of the earth. Whilst "is round" suggests some stability in earth description. *I realized that i am just rewording Antons answer*.

Comment: I don't know the context of the story. Can Pikachu's world change in shape?  If Pikachu lives in our world then our common sense tells us the world hasn't changed. We don't need to exclude changes.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough guide, I think your first applies best when the general truth still applies. I would therefore prefer your first. The second applies best when the once-general truth is no longer true. For example - he walked into Stalingrad, unaware that the city was in ruins. (I have altered my own "was destroyed" to chasly's rather nicer version "in ruins".)

Comment: "Destroyed" is ambiguous there. It could be past participle or adjective. Maybe "...unaware that the city was in ruins."

Comment: Quite right. I have altered my answer accordingly.